# F# how remove variables in function

Tags: .net, functional-programming, f#

I am refactoring a program in F# trying to do it 100% without the keyword  mutable but I have a problem in this one function:

```
  let ReadAndProcessCardData() = 
      let mutable pasobyte = serialPort1.BytesToRead
      let mutable pasobyte2 = 0

      while (pasobyte <> pasobyte2) 
            do
              pasobyte <- serialPort1.BytesToRead
              Thread.Sleep(2);
              pasobyte2 <- serialPort1.BytesToRead

      let mutable arr = [| for i in 1..serialPort1.BytesToRead -> byte(i*i)|]
      serialPort1.Read( arr , 0 , arr.Length ) |>ignore
      ByteArrayToString(arr) |> printCardGuid
```

I am trying to wait for a couple of milliseconds and check if the stream arriving at the Serial Port is over or it is still more data coming  but the property BytesToRead changes up to the time I read it,  if I compile the function as recursive instead of the while loop it gets the value as a constant, I am aware it is an impure function, what I am wondering is what is the correct way to refactor the function and how to change it to make it 100 functional as pure as possible and remove the word mutable but keep the behavior.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show your attempt to make the function recursive and explain what was wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the `while` loop into a recursive function with little work. Furthermore it may be better to pass the serial port as a parameter. The function would then look approximately like this:

```
let readAndProcessCardData (sp : System.IO.Ports.SerialPort) =
    let rec waitLoop b1 b2 =
        if b1 = b2 then b1 else
            let bb1 = sp.BytesToRead
            Thread.Sleep 2
            let bb2 = sp.BytesToRead
            waitLoop bb1 bb2
    let readLen = waitLoop 0 1
    let arr = Array.zeroCreate readLen
    sp.Read (arr, 0, arr.Length) |> ignore
    byteArrayToString arr |> printCardGuid
```

Comment: I had to change only the line  let arr = Array.zeroCreate readLen

Comment: for this one: let arr = [| for i in 1..serialPort1.BytesToRead -> byte(i*i)|]